# laravel 5 error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a question about Laravel 5.7. I have a multi-tenant project, and the issue is that when generating migrations, the admin is created without any problems. However, when I try to create a client, the client's database is not created, and the following error appears:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist`

The problem seems to be related to the database, in my case, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.43, Laravel 5.7 and PHP 7.4.33. I hope someone has found a solution. Thanks in advance.

Add my MySQL user in the .env file, but it's not creating the client's database.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's wrong if you don't post any code?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html for a general explanation of this error.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't provide any code because it's not a code issue; it was related to MySQL. The system works fine on other platforms, but the problem occurred on my machine, in my local development environment. Anyone who has encountered this issue and has resolved it would understand.

Comment: You have code that's making MySQL queries, it's running into this error.

Comment: Something is trying to reference a nonexistent savepoint in a `ROLLBACK` statement, it's not happening all by itself. It might be in Laravel, it might be in your code, it's impossible to tell from what you've posted. This isn't normal MySQL behavior, it doesn't get errors like this for no reason.

Comment: Because the system is a purchased code and works without any issues, as it operates with multi-tenancy, the actual problem was that it wasn't creating the users or the client databases for tenancy. But thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: With the information given, do you think anyone can help yoU?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve with docker, this my docker-file.com

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  php-apache:
    container_name: my_container_name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/app
  database:
      image: mysql:5.7
      restart: no #always
      container_name: my_container_name_to_db
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
        MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      ports:
        - '3306:3306'
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: How does this differ from the original docker file? Without seeing what was wrong, this is not a very helpful answer for future readers.

Comment: This error is not common; very few people will encounter this issue.

Comment: Then what's the point of posting an answer? The purpose of this site is to hold solutions to problems that future programmers can refer to.

Comment: That's why, I had an issue, managed to solve it, and I'm sharing it for anyone who might be interested. Why keep the solution to myself when it could help someone else?

Comment: But how will anyone understand the answer, or even know if they have the same problem, if you don't show the original version in the question?